# Как параметр в LIKE '%%' в подготовленном выражении

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, yii2

Работаю с `yii 2`. Имеется такой запрос

```
$films = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT descr, poster FROM {{films}} WHERE [[name_orig]] LIKE '%:filmname%'")
           ->bindParam(':filmname', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR)
           ->queryAll();
```

Он не работает. Проблема в участке `LIKE '%:filmname%'`

Всё работает если запрос упростить и написать так:

```
$films = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT descr, poster FROM {{films}} WHERE [[name_orig]] LIKE :filmname")
           ->bindParam(':filmname', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR)
           ->queryAll();
```

Подскажите, как переписать запрос, чтобы работало `LIKE '%:filmname%'`

Comment: А разве в документации ничего нет про это? Там же все описано

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так `'%'.$name.'%'`

```
$films = Yii::$app->db
    ->createCommand("SELECT descr, poster FROM {{films}} WHERE [[name_orig]] LIKE :filmname")
    ->bindParam(':filmname', '%'.$name.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR)
    ->queryAll();
```

Comment: А что насчет возможности провести sql-инъекцию?

Comment: это же проверяется до появления `$name`

Comment: при использовании обычного `mysql_query` тоже *должно* проверяться выше, а вот как по факту будет неизвестно. Я могу чуть позже написать ответ с правильным вариантом (без `createCommand`).